# Symfony2 get route name without locale prefix

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to translate my website with [JMSTtranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle) and Symfony2.7.

I am trying to make a language switcher. So i need to get the current route name and create new routes with it for other languages.

```
{% set route_params = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') %}
{% set route_params = route_params|merge(app.request.query.all) %}
<ul>
    {% for culture in cultures %}
        {% set route_params = route_params|merge({'_locale': culture.id}) %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), route_params) }}">
                {{ culture.name }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The app.request.attributes.get('_route') should return the route name like 'homepage', but it return the route prefix by locale like 'en__RG__homepage'.

Because of this, the route created for each language is the same that the current.

It is possible to get the route name without this prefix?

---

EDIT

For example, my homepage route definition is :

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: APPBundle:Default:index }
```

And in my jms config:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, fr]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

So, routes are translate in routes.en.xliff and routes.fr.xliff

Comment: I think it's because u don't handle correctly the locale var in your route definition. Can you show us the route definition of `en__RG__homepage`?

Comment: I don't know about jmstranslation bundle, but why not change homepage pattern by `/{_locale}` ?